# ARM Linux: how do sys_execv update the user stack

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I'm a newbie in Linux and I'm confused about the `sys_execv` function.

As I understand it, `sys_execv` will use `load_elf_binary` to load new binary and then invoke `start_thread` function to update the new pc and spsr. After that, it will jump to `ret_fast_syscall`, then with `restore_user_regs` it can return to the user space.

But I can't see anywhere update the user stack. If no one update the user stack, it will return to user space in the location of the old user stack?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the step where the kernel puts stuff on the new process stack.
The format is the same as described in this file https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/libc/private/KernelArgumentBlock.h

`glibc` does similarly https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/csu/libc-start.c

This is called 'kernel argument block' and consists of `argc`, `argv`, `envp`, and `auxv`.

Kernel fills `argc`, `argv` and `envp` in http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.4/source/fs/exec.c using `copy_strings`.

`auxv` values are filled in http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.4/source/fs/binfmt_elf.c - using `fill_auxv_note`

Eventually, `sp` in the new process is set using `#define start_thread(regs,pc,sp)` macro in http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.4/source/arch/arm/include/asm/processor.h#L56 - and called from http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.4/source/fs/binfmt_elf.c#L1085 using `start_thread(regs, elf_entry, bprm->p);`